# How to Return Ajax Result, Using a callback function and store in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Am trying to store Client Details In a Variable and display it for which i have used following code

```
let val = [];
val = get_clientDetails({"recursive":false});

console.log(val) // It's Prints Undefined.
```

```
function get_clientDetails(param)

    if(param.recursive == true){
        
        console.log(param.data); // It prints the ajax response. It works good till here. 
        return param.data;

    } else{

        let objClientDetails = new clientDetails();
        objClientDetails.client_details();        

    }

}
```

```
class clientDetails(){


client_details(){
      
        $.ajax({

            url: 'http://108.157.126.128:/clients',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async:false,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": 'Bearer '+sessionStorage.getItem('access_token')},
            success: function(client_data){

                
                get_clientDetails({"recursive": true, "data": client_data});



            }
        });
        
    }

}
```

When the above code Gets executed am unable to print the value returned from the callback function.
The code works good till we print the response in the callback function I.E get_clientDetails(). But when the function returns the value it prints as undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to receive data from AJAX call, inside the same function,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951747/how-to-receive-data-from-ajax-call-inside-the-same-function)

Comment: Hello @SivakumarTadisetti, Thanks for your response. But it doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti, I had tried and checked this thread earlier. it still din work for me

Comment: Hey @Dilkush but your question looks same as shared threads! what are the issues still you are facing?

Comment: I think am not clear in understanding the thread which you had suggested @SivakumarTadisetti

Comment: How you will be going to use `val` after getting some value into it?

Comment: val consists of a list of data. which i'll be using to display in a table after filtering it.

Comment: Use promise object.

Answer (score 0):

```
            class clientDetails {

                client_details() {

                    var result;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://108.157.126.128:/clients',
                        method: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        async: false, //>>>>>> ALWAY IN MODE FALSE.
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access_token')},
                        success: (client_data) => {

                            result = get_clientDetails({"recursive": true, "data": client_data});
                        },
                        error: (a) => {

                            result = "error";
                        }
                    });

                    return result;

                }

            }

            function get_clientDetails(param) {


                    if (param.recursive === true) {

                        console.log(param.data); // It prints the ajax response. It works good till here. 
                        return param.data;


                    } else {

                        let objClientDetails = new clientDetails();
                        return objClientDetails.client_details();

                    }

             }

             var result = get_clientDetails({"recursive": false});

             alert(result);
```

Comment: Hello @toto, Your above Code Works fine, But i want to save the result directly in a variable when get_clientDetails() is called. Is there a better way to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, The other way is using Global variable scope. Confirm me if you need an example.